# Binding Mysql to Magnolia cms on Cloud Foundry

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry, magnolia

I try to use mysql as database for Magnolia Cms on Cloud foundry.

I create a mysql service on cloud foundry.

and changed to magnolia.properties as below.

> magnolia.repositories.jackrabbit.config=WEB-INF/config/repo-conf/jackrabbit-bundle-mysql-search.xml

also configured the ***jackrabbit-bundle-mysql-search.xml*** and add the datasource as below :

```
<DataSources>
<DataSource name="magnolia">
    <param name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <param name="url" value="jdbc:${vcap.services.user-provided.author_magnolia_db.credentials.type}://${vcap.services.user-provided.author_magnolia_db.credentials.host}:${vcap.services.user-provided.author_magnolia_db.credentials.port}/${vcap.services.user-provided.author_magnolia_db.credentials.name}"/>
    <param name="user" value="${vcap.services.user-provided.author_magnolia_db.credentials.username}"/>
    <param name="password" value="${vcap.services.user-provided.author_magnolia_db.credentials.password}"/>
    <param name="databaseType" value="mysql"/>
    <param name="validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
</DataSource>
```

and i push the magnolia using below manifest.yml file.

> ---
>
> applications:
>   - name: magnolia
>     memory: 2G
>     path: magnolia-app.war
>     timeout: 360
>     services:
>       - magnolia

But even all these settings i couldnt deploy it to cloud foundry. What could be the reason?

Comment: There's no possible way anyone can tell unless you provide some more detail. What is the `cf push` command you're running? What is the full output from that command? What do you see in your application logs as the app tries to start (i.e. `cf logs --recent`)? That should get things started.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that any read that you make to `VCAP_SERVICES` should be in your application's bootstrap-configuration (the First thing to have this configured before your Application starts).

Also ensure that the *Application & the Marketplace service* is **binded** properly

Suppose if you are running a `Spring-boot` App, you need to have the configurations injected in your `bootstrap.yml`